# Style only the first item in a list (BUT, not if it has a specific class name)

Tags: css

I have a list of pagination links, and I want to style only the first and last items differently:

```
<ul class="pagination">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

This works perfectly:

```
.pagination li:first-child {background: blue;}
```

The problem is, sometimes (depending on what page you are on), there are next & previous links. For example:

```
<ul class="pagination">
    <li class="prev">Prev</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li class="next">Next</li>
</ul>
```

These next & prev  items are not always visible, so this causes my css to not work perfectly.

I know I can use ":not(.prev)", however, this doesn't seem to work together with "first-child".

I tried it like this:

```
.pagination li:not(.next):first-child {background: blue;}
```

and also, the other way around:

```
.pagination li:first-child:not(.next) {background: blue;}
```

Neither one of these options work, because it doesn't consider the second item to be the first item (in cases where the "prev" item is shown).

Is there a better way to do this with pure css?
I know this would be easier if the numbers had their own class names, but unfortunately it doesn't, and I'm hoping I don't have to edit the PHP.

Comment: You can't directly combine these with classes, as the duplicate explains. You could write more intricate selectors in your CSS though, to try and handle the issue. The first one you could handle via `:not(.prev):first-child, .prev + li` - if the first child does _not_ have the class `prev`, then it will be matched by the first part, and if there is one, its next following LI sibling will be targeted.

Comment: It doesn't work the other way around though, so for that you would have to also use `:has()` first of all (no default support in Firefox yet) on the `ul` level to determine whether a `.last` exists or not.